# Safecracker File: Rename on Upload

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads

How can I rename files uploaded via Safecracker?

More specifically, I would like to prefix the file name with the logged in user's username, convert to lower case & replace spaces with hyphens.

I was using [safecracker_file_add_prefix](https://github.com/rsanchez/safecracker_file_add_prefix/tree/lowercase-hyphens)

However, it no longer works since I upgraded from 2.4.0 to 2.5.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is due to a new change in the safecracker/libraries/safecracker_lib.php file for 2.5.3. It seems to be causing a lot of issues (like preventing the use of Safecracker in a Matrix field). Here's a forum link: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/224822/P18/#1040436

Go to line 230 in safecracker_lib.php and you'll see the following:

```
        if (isset($_FILES[$field['field_name']]['name']))
        {
            $_POST[$field['field_name']] = $_FILES[$field['field_name']];
        }
```

Comment out **$_POST[$field['field_name']] = $_FILES[$field['field_name']];**

```
        if (isset($_FILES[$field['field_name']]['name']))
        {
            /* HACK ppohler 11/13/2012, fix issue with Safecracker inside of Matrix */
            //$_POST[$field['field_name']] = $_FILES[$field['field_name']]['name'];
            /* HACK */
        }
```

Now safecracker_add_prefix should work (as well as Matrix). Keep in mind you'll want to log that you've made this change in core somewhere in case you need to update EE.

Comment: Thanks Patrick!

I tried commenting out the line mentioned. However, now the file upload field doesn't validate & therefore the form does not get submitted & file is not uploaded.

Is there something I can change in the safecracker_file_add_prefix file?

Any other suggestions or ways to accomplish same goal?

Comment: Andrea, did you manage to get this working? About to start a project where there will be many user submitted images/files and need a way to rename upon upload.

Comment: I'd also like to know if this was achieved? I'm allowing people to upload a logo via safecracker, and would ideally like to have it renamed.

Comment: I never did get this working. I don't have the programming skills necessary to modify the plugin so that is works in EE 2.5.3.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Rob has an updated version for Channel Form here:
https://github.com/rsanchez/channel_form_file_add_prefix/