# Safecracker file extensions

Tags: safecracker, safecracker-file

I'd like to lowercase filename & extension on file upload with safecracker. Does someone know where to find the pre-uploading bit in the code?

I've played around with the core set_filename method, but that only seems to affect the temp_ filenames.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was using an add-on to do something similar. However it broke when I upgraded from 2.4.0 to 2.5.3. See thread: [Safecracker File: Rename on Upload](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/526/safecracker-file-rename-on-upload)